# how to get the parent div ID using javascript selenium?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I am using webdriverjs, and i want to get the parent id of a webelement.There are multiple classes called row but each has a different id. The challenge is ID gets generated when a message is sent. so i can grab the innerHtml by class and then try to fetch the Id. 
I have the below html,

```
<div class="row" id="4003">
<div class="client-chat">
<p class="client-chat-text">If you have any questions, don’t hesitate to message me. I’m here to help with whatever you need!<span class="chat-time">Feb 01 2017 11:30:57</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="4361" class="row">
<div class="coach-chat">
<p class="coach-chat-text">
hi
</p>
</div>
```

the second div that is with id(4361) is the generated one which i need to grab for my testing. However, I am able to fetch **coach-chat-text** . How do i get the parent element in selenium. I have tried the below code, but i don't know how to get the parent id.

```
it('send a text message now',function(done){
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css("#messageField")).sendKeys('Hi');
            driver.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(".//*[@id='sendMessage']")).click().then(function(){
                driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className("coach-chat-text")).getText().then(function(text){
                    var message = text.slice(0,2);
                    //i want to fetch the parent id here.
                    try {
                        expect(message).to.equal("www.pluma.co");
                        done();
                    } catch (e) {
                        done(e);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `webdriver.By.xpath` to find the element with a class of 'coach-chat-text', then you could use the XPath parent selector - `/parent::node()` - to find the parent element.

Something like the following, although your XPath will probably vary:

`driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(".//*[contains(@class, 'coach-chat-text')]/parent::node()"));`